# Invoke unit tests after building target - boilermake

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using `boilermake` to build a unit test suite. After the target has been built successfully I would like the unit tests to be executed.

I have achieved this so far by using `TGT_POSTMAKE` in `main.mk` to specify that the target is executed after it is built.

```
TGT_POSTMAKE := \
    echo Running unit tests; \
            cd .. && \
            targets/my-test-suite
```

When I type `make` the unit test suite is built, if it is out of date, and then executed. If I type `make` again, it informs me that`Nothing to be done for 'all'`.

I would like to be able to run the unit tests even when the target is up to date. How do I achieve this? Even better if I could achieve it by typing `make test`.

Is this possible?

Here is a simplified version of my makefile, which is included by the top-level makefile of boilermake.

```
INCDIRS := \
    ../component1/include \
    ../component2/include \
    ../component3/include

CXXFLAGS := O2 -pipe -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-cast -pedantic \
    -isystem boost

SUBMAKEFILES := \
    ../component1/build/component1.mk \
    ../component2/build/component3.mk \
    ../component3/build/component4.mk

TARGET := my-test-suite

TGT_LDFLAGS := -L. -L${TARGET_DIR} 

TGT_LDLIBS  := -lcomponent1 -lcomponent2 -lcomponent3 \
    libboost_date_time-mt-sd.a \
    libboost_filesystem-mt-sd.a
    libcrypto.a \
    libssl.a \
    -lz \
    -ldl \
    -lpthread

TGT_PREREQS := \
    libcomponent1.a \
    libcomponent2.a \
    libcomponent3.a

SOURCES := \
    main.cpp

TGT_POSTMAKE := \
    echo Running unit tests; \
            cd .. && \
            targets/my-test-suite
```

Here is the boilermake makefile.

```
# boilermake: A reusable, but flexible, boilerplate Makefile.
#
# Copyright 2008, 2009, 2010 Dan Moulding, Alan T. DeKok
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

# Caution: Don't edit this Makefile! Create your own main.mk and other
#          submakefiles, which will be included by this Makefile.
#          Only edit this if you need to modify boilermake's behavior (fix
#          bugs, add features, etc).

# Note: Parameterized "functions" in this makefile that are marked with
#       "USE WITH EVAL" are only useful in conjuction with eval. This is
#       because those functions result in a block of Makefile syntax that must
#       be evaluated after expansion. Since they must be used with eval, most
#       instances of "$" within them need to be escaped with a second "$" to
#       accomodate the double expansion that occurs when eval is invoked.

# ADD_CLEAN_RULE - Parameterized "function" that adds a new rule and phony
#   target for cleaning the specified target (removing its build-generated
#   files).
#
#   USE WITH EVAL
#
define ADD_CLEAN_RULE
    clean: clean_${1}
    .PHONY: clean_${1}
    clean_${1}:
    $$(strip rm -f ${TARGET_DIR}/${1} $${${1}_OBJS:%.o=%.[do]})
    $${${1}_POSTCLEAN}
endef

# ADD_OBJECT_RULE - Parameterized "function" that adds a pattern rule for
#   building object files from source files with the filename extension
#   specified in the second argument. The first argument must be the name of the
#   base directory where the object files should reside (such that the portion
#   of the path after the base directory will match the path to corresponding
#   source files). The third argument must contain the rules used to compile the
#   source files into object code form.
#
#   USE WITH EVAL
#
define ADD_OBJECT_RULE
${1}/%.o: ${2}
    ${3}
endef

# ADD_TARGET_RULE - Parameterized "function" that adds a new target to the
#   Makefile. The target may be an executable or a library. The two allowable
#   types of targets are distinguished based on the name: library targets must
#   end with the traditional ".a" extension.
#
#   USE WITH EVAL
#
define ADD_TARGET_RULE
    ifeq "$$(suffix ${1})" ".a"
        # Add a target for creating a static library.
        $${TARGET_DIR}/${1}: $${${1}_OBJS}
        @mkdir -p $$(dir $$@)
        $$(strip $${AR} $${ARFLAGS} $$@ $${${1}_OBJS})
        $${${1}_POSTMAKE}
    else
        # Add a target for linking an executable. First, attempt to select the
        # appropriate front-end to use for linking. This might not choose the
        # right one (e.g. if linking with a C++ static library, but all other
        # sources are C sources), so the user makefile is allowed to specify a
        # linker to be used for each target.
        ifeq "$$(strip $${${1}_LINKER})" ""
            # No linker was explicitly specified to be used for this target. If
            # there are any C++ sources for this target, use the C++ compiler.
            # For all other targets, default to using the C compiler.
            ifneq "$$(strip $$(filter $${CXX_SRC_EXTS},$${${1}_SOURCES}))" ""
                ${1}_LINKER = $${CXX}
            else
                ${1}_LINKER = $${CC}
            endif
        endif

        $${TARGET_DIR}/${1}: $${${1}_OBJS} $${${1}_PREREQS}
        @mkdir -p $$(dir $$@)
        $$(strip $${${1}_LINKER} -o $$@ $${LDFLAGS} $${${1}_LDFLAGS} \
            $${${1}_OBJS} $${LDLIBS} $${${1}_LDLIBS})
        $${${1}_POSTMAKE}
    endif
endef

# CANONICAL_PATH - Given one or more paths, converts the paths to the canonical
#   form. The canonical form is the path, relative to the project's top-level
#   directory (the directory from which "make" is run), and without
#   any "./" or "../" sequences. For paths that are not  located below the
#   top-level directory, the canonical form is the absolute path (i.e. from
#   the root of the filesystem) also without "./" or "../" sequences.
define CANONICAL_PATH
$(patsubst ${CURDIR}/%,%,$(abspath ${1}))
endef

# COMPILE_C_CMDS - Commands for compiling C source code.
define COMPILE_C_CMDS
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(strip ${CC} -o $@ -c -MP -MD ${CFLAGS} ${SRC_CFLAGS} ${INCDIRS} \
        ${SRC_INCDIRS} ${SRC_DEFS} ${DEFS} $<)
endef

# COMPILE_CXX_CMDS - Commands for compiling C++ source code.
define COMPILE_CXX_CMDS
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(strip ${CXX} -o $@ -c -MP -MD ${CXXFLAGS} ${SRC_CXXFLAGS} ${INCDIRS} \
        ${SRC_INCDIRS} ${SRC_DEFS} ${DEFS} $<)
endef

# INCLUDE_SUBMAKEFILE - Parameterized "function" that includes a new
#   "submakefile" fragment into the overall Makefile. It also recursively
#   includes all submakefiles of the specified submakefile fragment.
#
#   USE WITH EVAL
#
define INCLUDE_SUBMAKEFILE
    # Initialize all variables that can be defined by a makefile fragment, then
    # include the specified makefile fragment.
    TARGET        :=
    TGT_CFLAGS    :=
    TGT_CXXFLAGS  :=
    TGT_DEFS      :=
    TGT_INCDIRS   :=
    TGT_LDFLAGS   :=
    TGT_LDLIBS    :=
    TGT_LINKER    :=
    TGT_POSTCLEAN :=
    TGT_POSTMAKE  :=
    TGT_PREREQS   :=

    SOURCES       :=
    SRC_CFLAGS    :=
    SRC_CXXFLAGS  :=
    SRC_DEFS      :=
    SRC_INCDIRS   :=

    SUBMAKEFILES  :=

    # A directory stack is maintained so that the correct paths are used as we
    # recursively include all submakefiles. Get the makefile's directory and
    # push it onto the stack.
    DIR := $(call CANONICAL_PATH,$(dir ${1}))
    DIR_STACK := $$(call PUSH,$${DIR_STACK},$${DIR})

    include ${1}

    # Initialize internal local variables.
    OBJS :=

    # Ensure that valid values are set for BUILD_DIR and TARGET_DIR.
    ifeq "$$(strip $${BUILD_DIR})" ""
        BUILD_DIR := build
    endif
    ifeq "$$(strip $${TARGET_DIR})" ""
        TARGET_DIR := .
    endif

    # Determine which target this makefile's variables apply to. A stack is
    # used to keep track of which target is the "current" target as we
    # recursively include other submakefiles.
    ifneq "$$(strip $${TARGET})" ""
        # This makefile defined a new target. Target variables defined by this
        # makefile apply to this new target. Initialize the target's variables.
        TGT := $$(strip $${TARGET})
        ALL_TGTS += $${TGT}
        $${TGT}_CFLAGS    := $${TGT_CFLAGS}
        $${TGT}_CXXFLAGS  := $${TGT_CXXFLAGS}
        $${TGT}_DEFS      := $${TGT_DEFS}
        $${TGT}_DEPS      :=
        TGT_INCDIRS       := $$(call QUALIFY_PATH,$${DIR},$${TGT_INCDIRS})
        TGT_INCDIRS       := $$(call CANONICAL_PATH,$${TGT_INCDIRS})
        $${TGT}_INCDIRS   := $${TGT_INCDIRS}
        $${TGT}_LDFLAGS   := $${TGT_LDFLAGS}
        $${TGT}_LDLIBS    := $${TGT_LDLIBS}
        $${TGT}_LINKER    := $${TGT_LINKER}
        $${TGT}_OBJS      :=
        $${TGT}_POSTCLEAN := $${TGT_POSTCLEAN}
        $${TGT}_POSTMAKE  := $${TGT_POSTMAKE}
        $${TGT}_PREREQS   := $$(addprefix $${TARGET_DIR}/,$${TGT_PREREQS})
        $${TGT}_SOURCES   :=
    else
        # The values defined by this makefile apply to the the "current" target
        # as determined by which target is at the top of the stack.
        TGT := $$(strip $$(call PEEK,$${TGT_STACK}))
        $${TGT}_CFLAGS    += $${TGT_CFLAGS}
        $${TGT}_CXXFLAGS  += $${TGT_CXXFLAGS}
        $${TGT}_DEFS      += $${TGT_DEFS}
        TGT_INCDIRS       := $$(call QUALIFY_PATH,$${DIR},$${TGT_INCDIRS})
        TGT_INCDIRS       := $$(call CANONICAL_PATH,$${TGT_INCDIRS})
        $${TGT}_INCDIRS   += $${TGT_INCDIRS}
        $${TGT}_LDFLAGS   += $${TGT_LDFLAGS}
        $${TGT}_LDLIBS    += $${TGT_LDLIBS}
        $${TGT}_POSTCLEAN += $${TGT_POSTCLEAN}
        $${TGT}_POSTMAKE  += $${TGT_POSTMAKE}
        $${TGT}_PREREQS   += $${TGT_PREREQS}
    endif

    # Push the current target onto the target stack.
    TGT_STACK := $$(call PUSH,$${TGT_STACK},$${TGT})

    ifneq "$$(strip $${SOURCES})" ""
        # This makefile builds one or more objects from source. Validate the
        # specified sources against the supported source file types.
        BAD_SRCS := $$(strip $$(filter-out $${ALL_SRC_EXTS},$${SOURCES}))
        ifneq "$${BAD_SRCS}" ""
            $$(error Unsupported source file(s) found in ${1} [$${BAD_SRCS}])
        endif

        # Qualify and canonicalize paths.
        SOURCES     := $$(call QUALIFY_PATH,$${DIR},$${SOURCES})
        SOURCES     := $$(call CANONICAL_PATH,$${SOURCES})
        SRC_INCDIRS := $$(call QUALIFY_PATH,$${DIR},$${SRC_INCDIRS})
        SRC_INCDIRS := $$(call CANONICAL_PATH,$${SRC_INCDIRS})

        # Save the list of source files for this target.
        $${TGT}_SOURCES += $${SOURCES}

        # Convert the source file names to their corresponding object file
        # names.
        OBJS := $$(addprefix $${BUILD_DIR}/$$(call CANONICAL_PATH,$${TGT})/,\
                   $$(addsuffix .o,$$(basename $${SOURCES})))

        # Add the objects to the current target's list of objects, and create
        # target-specific variables for the objects based on any source
        # variables that were defined.
        $${TGT}_OBJS += $${OBJS}
        $${TGT}_DEPS += $${OBJS:%.o=%.d}
        $${OBJS}: SRC_CFLAGS   := $${$${TGT}_CFLAGS} $${SRC_CFLAGS}
        $${OBJS}: SRC_CXXFLAGS := $${$${TGT}_CXXFLAGS} $${SRC_CXXFLAGS}
        $${OBJS}: SRC_DEFS     := $$(addprefix -D,$${$${TGT}_DEFS} $${SRC_DEFS})
        $${OBJS}: SRC_INCDIRS  := $$(addprefix -I,\
                                     $${$${TGT}_INCDIRS} $${SRC_INCDIRS})
    endif

    ifneq "$$(strip $${SUBMAKEFILES})" ""
        # This makefile has submakefiles. Recursively include them.
        $$(foreach MK,$${SUBMAKEFILES},\
           $$(eval $$(call INCLUDE_SUBMAKEFILE,\
                      $$(call CANONICAL_PATH,\
                         $$(call QUALIFY_PATH,$${DIR},$${MK})))))
    endif

    # Reset the "current" target to it's previous value.
    TGT_STACK := $$(call POP,$${TGT_STACK})
    TGT := $$(call PEEK,$${TGT_STACK})

    # Reset the "current" directory to it's previous value.
    DIR_STACK := $$(call POP,$${DIR_STACK})
    DIR := $$(call PEEK,$${DIR_STACK})
endef

# MIN - Parameterized "function" that results in the minimum lexical value of
#   the two values given.
define MIN
$(firstword $(sort ${1} ${2}))
endef

# PEEK - Parameterized "function" that results in the value at the top of the
#   specified colon-delimited stack.
define PEEK
$(lastword $(subst :, ,${1}))
endef

# POP - Parameterized "function" that pops the top value off of the specified
#   colon-delimited stack, and results in the new value of the stack. Note that
#   the popped value cannot be obtained using this function; use peek for that.
define POP
${1:%:$(lastword $(subst :, ,${1}))=%}
endef

# PUSH - Parameterized "function" that pushes a value onto the specified colon-
#   delimited stack, and results in the new value of the stack.
define PUSH
${2:%=${1}:%}
endef

# QUALIFY_PATH - Given a "root" directory and one or more paths, qualifies the
#   paths using the "root" directory (i.e. appends the root directory name to
#   the paths) except for paths that are absolute.
define QUALIFY_PATH
$(addprefix ${1}/,$(filter-out /%,${2})) $(filter /%,${2})
endef

###############################################################################
#
# Start of Makefile Evaluation
#
###############################################################################

# Older versions of GNU Make lack capabilities needed by boilermake.
# With older versions, "make" may simply output "nothing to do", likely leading
# to confusion. To avoid this, check the version of GNU make up-front and
# inform the user if their version of make doesn't meet the minimum required.
MIN_MAKE_VERSION := 3.81
MIN_MAKE_VER_MSG := boilermake requires GNU Make ${MIN_MAKE_VERSION} or greater
ifeq "${MAKE_VERSION}" ""
    $(info GNU Make not detected)
    $(error ${MIN_MAKE_VER_MSG})
endif
ifneq "${MIN_MAKE_VERSION}" "$(call MIN,${MIN_MAKE_VERSION},${MAKE_VERSION})"
    $(info This is GNU Make version ${MAKE_VERSION})
    $(error ${MIN_MAKE_VER_MSG})
endif

# Define the source file extensions that we know how to handle.
C_SRC_EXTS := %.c
CXX_SRC_EXTS := %.C %.cc %.cp %.cpp %.CPP %.cxx %.c++
ALL_SRC_EXTS := ${C_SRC_EXTS} ${CXX_SRC_EXTS}

# Initialize global variables.
ALL_TGTS :=
DEFS :=
DIR_STACK :=
INCDIRS :=
TGT_STACK :=

# Include the main user-supplied submakefile. This also recursively includes
# all other user-supplied submakefiles.
$(eval $(call INCLUDE_SUBMAKEFILE,main.mk))

# Perform post-processing on global variables as needed.
DEFS := $(addprefix -D,${DEFS})
INCDIRS := $(addprefix -I,$(call CANONICAL_PATH,${INCDIRS}))

# Define the "all" target (which simply builds all user-defined targets) as the
# default goal.
.PHONY: all
all: $(addprefix ${TARGET_DIR}/,${ALL_TGTS})

# Add a new target rule for each user-defined target.
$(foreach TGT,${ALL_TGTS},\
  $(eval $(call ADD_TARGET_RULE,${TGT})))

# Add pattern rule(s) for creating compiled object code from C source.
$(foreach TGT,${ALL_TGTS},\
  $(foreach EXT,${C_SRC_EXTS},\
    $(eval $(call ADD_OBJECT_RULE,${BUILD_DIR}/$(call CANONICAL_PATH,${TGT}),\
             ${EXT},$${COMPILE_C_CMDS}))))

# Add pattern rule(s) for creating compiled object code from C++ source.
$(foreach TGT,${ALL_TGTS},\
  $(foreach EXT,${CXX_SRC_EXTS},\
    $(eval $(call ADD_OBJECT_RULE,${BUILD_DIR}/$(call CANONICAL_PATH,${TGT}),\
             ${EXT},$${COMPILE_CXX_CMDS}))))

# Add "clean" rules to remove all build-generated files.
.PHONY: clean
$(foreach TGT,${ALL_TGTS},\
  $(eval $(call ADD_CLEAN_RULE,${TGT})))

# Include generated rules that define additional (header) dependencies.
$(foreach TGT,${ALL_TGTS},\
  $(eval -include ${${TGT}_DEPS}))
```

**UPDATE 13/02/2017**

I removed `TGT_POSTMAKE` and added the following into `main.mk` but now the tests are executed every time whether I enter `make` or `make test` at the command line.

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    cd .. && \
    targets/my-test-suite
```

Furthermore, no updates are carried out unless I enter `make all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. By adding the following to `main.mk` I get the behaviour I want.

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

.PHONY: test
test: all
    cd .. && \
    targets/my-test-suite
```

Entering `make` will update and run the tests if anything has changed.

Entering `make test` will update and run the tests if anything has changed or just run the unit tests if nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand idea of `TGT_POSTMAKE` hook. According to boilermake sources it adds extra shell commands to execute from recipe updating the target. So commands from `TGT_POSTMAKE` will be executed only when Make runs recipe to update `targets/my-test-suite` target.

But you want something different, right? I suggest you append the following fragment to your makefile:

```
run_my-test-suite: | targets/my-test-suite; @echo Running unit tests; cd .. && targets/my-test-suite
.PHONY: run_my-test-suite
```

You also need to remove `TGT_POSTMAKE :=...` assignment from you makefile.

Fragment explained:

Recipe for `run_my-test-suite` target will be executed after Make updates `my-test-suite` target (if such update is needed). If Make decides that `targets/my-test-suite` target is up to date, recipe for `run_my-test-suite` target will be still executed. Note seldom used `: |` syntax in `run_my-test-suite` rule. GNU Make Manual https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html:

> Occasionally, however, you have a situation where you want to impose a
>   specific ordering on the rules to be invoked without forcing the
>   target to be updated if one of those rules is executed. In that case,
>   you want to define order-only prerequisites. Order-only prerequisites
>   can be specified by placing a pipe symbol (|) in the prerequisites
>   list: any prerequisites to the left of the pipe symbol are normal; any
>   prerequisites to the right are order-only:

Command line to run tests: `make run_my-test-suite`. Note, that running `make run_my-test-suite` will not update `targets/my-test-suite` target if it is outdated.

Command line to update and run tests: `make run_my-test-suite targets/my-test-suite`

If you want `make run_my-test-suite` command to update and run tests, remove pipe symbol (`|`) from `run_my-test-suite` rule.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get an error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'my-test-suite', needed by 'run_my-test-suite'.  Stop`

Comment: @ksl, I have updated my answer. Seems like you don't have `my-test-suite` target, but have `targets/my-test-suite` instead.

Comment: The updated answer does not work either. The tests are run, without an update, every time, regardless of whether I enter `make`, `make run_my-test-suite` or `make run_my-test-suite targets/my-test-suite`. Also, removing the `|` has no effect either.

Comment: @ksl, you have different problem now, not the original one, right? So now you get unit tests executed every time you do `make test`, but they are not updated before run. To fix this you need to adjust prerequisites of `test` and `my-test-suite` targets.